# PostgreSQL create schema from within function trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, schema

My goal is to create a schema, based on the uuid of a user.
I've therfor wrote a function that gets executed every time a user is created and confirmed.

As the documentation says [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createtrigger.html)
[image: PostgreSQL Compatibility] i may have to write another function that creates a schema because of compatibility.

the 'create_user_schema()' function works in a new query but seems to not work if used in my trigger function. I've tried a lot with casting the uuid to a string but it still don't work.

Did i do something wrong, has this something to do with security and won't work in any case?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_setup() RETURNS trigger AS $user_setup$
    DECLARE
      s_name uuid := NEW.id;
    BEGIN
        -- cutout content that works so far

        SELECT create_user_schema(CAST(s_name AS TEXT));
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$user_setup$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER user_setup AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON auth.users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION user_setup();
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user_schema(s_name text) RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || quote_ident(s_name);
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Use `perform` not `select` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your guess, but this does not work too. I can see from the result set, that my function must fail at the moment of trying to create the schema. The schema function is well tested, of course so i thought it has something to do with the uuid casting.

Comment: [Works for me...](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yefad9nd)

Comment: @NickBarnes thank you for your time testing this. It looks like this problem has something to do with the underlying system inserting and updating the auth.users table. I've opened a bug report for that system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it wasn't really a bug and more some missing piece of information in "how postgres works".
It was necessary to add a 'Security Definer' keyword to the function to let the trigger have the correct privilges on execution.